# Stripping leading tab of each line from a file

Tags: python, strings, regex, file

I've got this Python code:

```
import os, re

def clnFile(file):
    inputFile = open(file, 'r')
    filename = file + '.tmp'
    outputFile = open(filename, 'w')
    code = inputFile.read()
    pattern = re.compile('\n\t')
    code = pattern.sub('\n', code)
    outputFile.write(code)
    inputFile.close()
    outputFile.close()
    os.remove(file)
    os.rename(filename, file)
```

It supposed to change content of the file. 
My algorithm is:

1. open original file
2. open original temporary file
3. read original file content to a string
4. change the string
5. write string to original temporary file
6. close original file
7. close temporary file
8. remove old original file
9. rename temporary file

I am sure there should be a way to simplify this code. Because now it's rather bulky.
Could anyone help me to adjust it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a different approach here:

1. Open file in [`r+` mode](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/inputoutput.html#reading-and-writing-files), it allows us to read as well as write the file along with truncation.
2. Read the content first and store it in a variable.
3. Seek back to 0th position using [`file.seek(0)`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#file.seek).
4. Truncate the file using [`file.truncate()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#file.truncate), i.e it will truncate it to 0 bytes.
5. Now write the new content to the file object.

**Code:**

```
def clean_file(filename):
    with open(filename, 'r+') as f:
        content = f.read()
        f.seek(0)
        f.truncate()
        f.write(content.replace('\n\t', '\n'))
```

Few other points:

- Prefer variable names with underscores in Python.
- Always open files using the [`with` statement](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/inputoutput.html#methods-of-file-objects) in Python.
- You can change the variable name `file` to `filename` to make it clearer to the user, otherwise it's hard to tell whether the file object expects a file name or file object.
- Instead of using regex simply use the [`str.replace`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.replace) method.
- To modify a file line by line in-place you can look into [`fileinput`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/fileinput.html#fileinput.FileInput) module.

Comment: Oh...I did not think about `with` statement. I've just started learning python so...I see.

Comment: This is definitely simpler. However, I should point out that unlike the original code, this is no longer atomic. (The difference would only manifest itself in the case of a catastrophe, such as the machine losing power while the file is being rewritten.)